# Why Reading Upload file and Reading Local file producing different results?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am posting file to python flask and then read its content using following code:

```
def post(self):
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return {'error': 'no file'}
        try:
          f=open("text2.txt")
          local_content=f.read()
          content=request.files['file'].read().decode('utf-8')
          if hash(content) != hash(local_content) :
            return {'error': 'content changed','local':hash(local_content),'uploaded':hash(content)}
          else:
            return {'error': 'same','local':hash(local_content),'uploaded':hash(content)}
```

I also put same file text2.txt on server and read it locally using

```
local_content=f.read()
```

but both results are different.I tried comparing two string using following

```
if content != local_content
```

above conditions is always returning true.
but when I print both strings they are exactly same.

I am doing some processing on those strings and trying and both content and local_content produces different results.

So can anyone tell me why uploaded content is behaving differently than local content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I face this issue while uploading images using flask. The binary streams were different as compared to reading local file.

I solve this issue with file.seek(0)

```
files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
for file in files:
     file.seek(0)
     fileBytes = file.read()
     image_stringRead = base64.b64encode(fileBytes)
```